# How to structure a minimal Dart Polymer app with a main()

Tags: dart, program-entry-point, dart-polymer

The Dart editor currently supports only one dart polymer (/file) new project generation option.  And this option sets up 4 files in the /web subdir without a main(), and arriving at a main requires some boiler-plate changes that were not totally obvious to me.

I was helped on the Dart Forum for this somewhat "howto" question by Guenter Zoeckbauer, so I want to share the results of those minimal changes to this nice minimal project, that has provided me with exactly the starting point need to re-base my outdated code and file structure on.

It seems to me it provides good starting point reference for re-building apps that have gotten out of date with all the rapid and IMPORTANT changes that have been made in the last few months.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the 6 files as they must be modified (the app name is:  app_with_main):

## 1  app_with_main.css    NO CHANGE

## 2  clickcounter.dart    NO CHANGE

## 3  clickcounter.html    NO CHANGE

## 4  index.html:

```dart
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sample app</title>
    <!-- <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
         not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="clickcounter.html">

    <!-- ORIGINAL SCRIPT
    <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app_with_main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>App with main</h1>

    <p>Hello world from Dart!</p>

    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <click-counter count="5"></click-counter>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart">export 'init.dart';</script>   

  </body>
</html>
```

#5 .  init.dart   (new)

import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";

```dart
main() {

  print("always before polymer initialization is complete");  

  initPolymer().run(() {

     print('''Code here will be called almost immediately and cannot rely 
              on the polymer elements being instantiated.''');

    Polymer.onReady.then((_) { 

      print('''at this point the onReady callback has been returned and thus the polymer 
      initialization process will be complete''');

    });
  });
```

## 6  The project yaml file must be modified to set the entry_point to index.html thus:

```dart
name: app_with_main
description: A sample Polymer application
dependencies:
    polymer: ">=0.11.0-dev.2 <0.12.0"
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
```

And that should do it, you should be off and running with a code structure that can grow with your project for a long time....

Thanks again to Dart Super Hero   Guenter Zoecchbauer!

Answer (score 1):

For reference and comparison I think it is useful to also consider the skeleton Polymer Dart app that gets generated by the [Chrome Dev Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-dev-editor-develop/pnoffddplpippgcfjdhbmhkofpnaalpg?hl=en).  It includes a Dart main().

Below I've posted index.html, and main.dart from the web folder of a freshly generated Polymer Dart Paper elements project (as of 2014-10-10).

Note that these reference a sample_app custom element which gets generated into the lib folder, but pasting that below as well would be too long.

**1.  Index.html**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>HelloDartWebPaper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="packages/HelloDartWebPaper/sample_app.html">
  </head>

  <body unresolved>
    <sample-app></sample-app>

    <script src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**2. main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_toast.dart';
import 'package:HelloDartWebPaper/sample_app.dart';

void main() {
  // Init polymer.
  initPolymer();

  // Register Polymer components (ones that are actually used in the app).
  registerWidgetsWithPolymer();
}

@initMethod
void postPolymerBoot() {
  print('Polymer init complete.');
}

void registerWidgetsWithPolymer() {
  upgradePaperToast();
  Polymer.register('sample-app', SampleApp);
}
```

3. styles.css
   omitted - not relevant
4. sample_app component in lib.